# Best Practice - Avoid naming class and field the same?

Tags: naming, class-design, naming-standards

When modeling classes I always have stumbled on the problem that the class has a field with the same name. Look at this example:

```cs
class Name {  
  string meaning;  
  string language;  
  string name; //the actual name
}
```

As you can see, the class Name has a field name, which is the actual name. Is this good practice? How to avoid this naming issue?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/name

Comment: @Ewan: I've spent many an hour browsing that site during "what do we call this thing" sessions. A thesaurus is usually a good first stop.

Comment: If it is not possible to choose a concise and clear name, it becomes more important that you provide suitable documentation about the roles and meanings of these classes or fields.

Comment: What does the class `Name` represent? It's hard to tell even with the properties specified.

Comment: Well, the class Name is just an example. 
I could imagine some application for popular baby names or something.

Comment: I would like rename one of them to "word".

Comment: @Barmar, [unless the name is more than one word](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Naming things is hard. Names are hard. Now what do we name this name...

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yeah, but this doesn't seem to be about people names.

Comment: You can opt adding a `T` (for "type") at the beginning of a classname, so you would have a `TName` class, having a `Name` property.

Comment: A couple of related issues for you to consider as you ponder this question. (1) never name a class the same as its containing namespace in C#. It is hard on the reader of the code and it makes the compiler's life more difficult because it introduces ambiguities. (2) By contrast, it is totally acceptable to name a field or property the same as its type. `Color Color {get; set;}` is the classic example. In your example, `class Whatever { Name Name {get; set;} ... }` is totally fine.

Comment: I think this is a good question with a lot of good answers, but that `Name` is a corner-case within the broader scope, given how it fits into English, so there may be less of a right answer than even as usual

Comment: From a linguistics point of view, the word for the property here is "form". This isn't an answer because it doesn't address the question of best practices, but hopefully it solves the X/Y problem in this particular case.

Answer (score 68):

[Bart van Ingen Schenau has some good advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/442832/118878), but I'd like to offer some additional advice.

Don't universally avoid naming a class and property the same, but definitely question it. Consider all of the properties together as one cohesive concept: name, language, and meaning. Rather than renaming the property, perhaps rename the class. This is more than a name.

Instead, pick a word or short phrase that describes the concept of the combination of a name, its meaning, and the language (or culture) for the name. For example, typically the combination of a word or phrase along with its meaning is called a "definition". The class could be called `NameDefinition`, which has a `name` property. The addition of the word "Definition" helps differentiate the type from the data in the type, while also communicating to consumers of this class that it is more than a simple string.

Comment: Good alternative indeed. I can imagine this approach is particularly useful in weakly typed languages.

Comment: BvIS said, in the answer to which you linked, "You should be able to ask, 'What is the <property> of the <class>?'" In OP's case, if it makes sense to call the class `Name`, then good names for the field might be `value`, or `text`. E.g., What is the _value_ of the name? What is the _text_ of the name?

Answer (score 40):

Fields/properties/attributes within a class should describe something of the concept that you are modelling with that class. You should be able to ask questions like "What is the <property> of the <class>?" without having domain experts going "what the heck are you talking about?".

Typically, it is not a good idea to have an attribute with the same name as the class, because the attribute name doesn't describe anything meaningful *within the context of the class*. Probably it is more meaningful to name such an attribute 'value'. As in, the value of a Name object is the actual name being represented by that object.

Comment: Or *spelling* in this case, as in What is the spelling of the name

Answer (score 9):

`name.name()` feels rather silly (why say the same thing twice?). `name.value()` is better as in you don't have to repeat yourself, but it's a bit vague (what is the value of a name?). It might be worth it to add more intent to these properties. So, `name.displayName()` feels more meaningful if I am about to display that name somewhere. It also gives the flexibility that the display name maybe specialized in some way depending on the context. Similarly, `name.ipaName()` for any phonetic use, `name.utf8()` for transportation/serialization, etc.

Comment: why not `name.display` or `name.ipa`? since we don't want to repeat the same thing twice.

Comment: Does ipaName apply to beer?

Comment: @Hugo `name.display` sounds like it is going to 'display' the name? It's good to avoid the ambiguity. If you can find a non-confusing alternative that is similarly expressive, go for it. Maybe something like `name.displayRepresentation()`. That's a bit too verbose though. But at least that is the kind of name I would strive for.

Comment: @user949300 [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)

Answer (score 0):

The general advice is to name things *for the reader*, so that they are understood *when they are read*.

Perhaps it will help you to consider all the *contexts in which the thing appears* (here a class name and/or a field/property name).

- In the definition of the class. Here, you want it both to be somewhat meaning full by itself, and *with respect to* the class/thing (i.e. as a property of the thing, "the `XXX` of a `Y`"; in your example "the `name` of a `Name`" is dubious; perhaps you can use something like `text` or `writtenAs`). See [Bart's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/442832/271624).
- When used in code external to the class. Here it will be attached to the name of a variable. Example for "the `dbid` of an `item`":

  ```
   foreach item in recordset:
       print item.dbid
  ```

  In your case/example :

  ```
   Name selectedName = FindGoodName(some query or constraints);
   print selectedName.text;
  ```

  or

  ```
   print selectedName.writtenAs;
  ```

  or whatever you find appropriate.
- In the code internal to the class; this is relevant for *private* fields, but is perhaps of lowest priority for a *public* property/field.

(I'm probably forgetting some context(s)... )

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with just about all of these answers (and while it obviously depends on constraints and use cases), I think it can be important to consider the informational hierarchy with relation to importance/usage context, i.e:

```
class Person {
    string name;
    Biography biography;

    class Biography {
        string nameMeaning;
        string nameLanguageOrigin;
    }
}
```

Obviously your mileage may vary (and is dependent on your requirements), but I mean to point out that just because two topics are related (such as the "name" and the "meaning"), doesn't mean that they're often used in the same *context*, which could mean they should sit in different "buckets" when designing classes.